# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring

I try to make a Authentication JWT but when i throw my app, throw me this error:

```
WARN 18692 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing
```

I get a 400 Bad Request error saying the Request Body is missing

```
{
"timestamp": "2021-10-06T05:33:49.501+00:00",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"path": "/task-market/api/auth/authenticate"}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/authenticate")
public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> createToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request) {
    try {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));
        UserDetails userDetails = marketUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(request.getUsername());
        String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

this is the security layer:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**/authenticate").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

Comment: Can you put your request body? @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52680158/null-check-for-request-body-object/52680212#52680212

Comment: Can you please post your request?
How do you perform the request?
You are missing the JSON Body most likely.

Comment: Where can i find the request body?

Comment: curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/task-market/api/auth/authenticate' \
--data-raw ''

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the username and password to **Body**

like

```
{
"username":"your_username"
"password":"your_password"
}
```

and need to change the media type `Text` to `JSON`